# HTML legend element not being counted in form

Tags: html, forms, element

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript &amp; jQuery - Chapter 13: Form Enhancement and Validation - Select All Checkboxes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/c13.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container login">
      <form id="interests" action="/login" method="post">
        <div class="one-third column">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo" />
        </div>
        <div class="two-thirds column" id="main">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Genres</legend>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="all" id="all">All</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="animation">Animation</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="docs">Documentary</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="shorts">Shorts</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div><!-- .two-thirds -->
      </form>
  </div><!-- .container -->
  <script src="js/utilities.js"></script>
  <script src="js/all-checkboxes.js"></script>
</body>
```

In the all-checkbox.js file, I have the following lines:

```
...
var form = document.getElementById('interests');
var elements = form.elements;
...
```

When I load the page and examine the elements variable in the debugger (Firefox), I see it is an array of length 5. My understanding is that form.elements will return all elements of the form. The debugger shows the following values for elements:

```
0: <fieldset> 
1: <input#all> 
2: <input> 
3: <input> 
4: <input>
```

I thought that the legend element was also a form element, but it is obviously not being counted as such here.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` returns an [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) object. `legend` is not a [listed element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-listed) in the [elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-elements) property of it.

As to *why*... /shrug. I can't seem to find any backstory. If I had to take a guess though, I'd say because it's not an actual control element for the form, and perhaps the powers-that-be feel `HTMLFORMElement.elements` means "control" elements. But again, just speculation.

Comment: I think you nailed it, I just found this on the Mozilla Developer Network: The HTMLFormElement.elements property returns an HTMLFormControlsCollection (HTML 4 HTMLCollection) of all the form controls contained in the FORM element, with the exception of input elements which have a type attribute of image.